# calculating differences between entries in a table using each entry or skipping entries after rounding

Tags: number-theory

Entry two of a table is entry one plus or minus some number.  Each entry is determined by adding or subtracting some value to/from the previous entry.  The value varies.  The entries are composed of six digits to the right of the decimal.  Is the following true and is there a theory that explains it?  (entry two rounded to two decimals minus entry one rounded to two decimals) plus (entry three rounded to two decimals minus entry two rounded to two decimals) will result in the same value as (entry three rounded to two decimals minus entry one rounded to two decimals).  Typically the first calculation will be entry n rounded to two decimals minus entry n-3 rounded to two decimals.  The second calculation uses every entry.  These must come up with the same answer or I need to find another approach.

Comment: "The value varies."  Does it vary from entry to entry, or does it vary with the passage of time?  "These must come up with the same answer or I need to find another approach."  Or perhaps come up with a different table.

Answer (score 0):

The rounding stuff is distracting from the essentials. Call entry $k$ rounded to two decimals $r_k$. Then you're asking why $(r_2-r_1)+(r_3-r_2)=(r_3-r_1)$. This is basic arithmetic: $r_2$ cancels on the left.